# Linear Algebra; computational problems

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

I dug this problem up from an old exam. I am not asking how to solve them, but I want to get a "feel" for the problem. I could technically solve this brutally,I just want to develop some problem solving skills.

> [image]

For (a), I notice that the first two vectors must be part of the basis. The only problem are the last two vectors. Is there a way (without computing) to determine whether one of them belongs to the basis or not? I do not want check whether one of them is a linear combination of the other or not.

(b) **misread** the problem. **edit**: looks another row-reduction problem...but correct me if I am wrong.

(c) Looks like another annoying row-reduction problem.

Comment: Maybe you can do something like this to see if the third vector , say $v_3$is independent of the first two:if it is a lin.comb. then, looking at the top entry $v_3$ must be $2v_1+v_2$. But then the other entries do not match. But then to see if $v_4$ is independent of the others, it becomes harder. I don't see how you could avoid doing something like Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Isn't your method, essentially is Gaussian Elimination? I want to avoid doing that, in every possible way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here were my initial thoughts on how to solve each part.

Hint for a:

Find the reduced form of the matrix whose columns are the given vectors, and then take those vectors corresponding to columns with leading ones.

Hint for b:

If two vectors are orthogonal, their dot product is $0$.

Hint for c:

Express the given vector as a linear combination of the vector given in part a.  For the three known components, you should obtain a system of equations (three unknowns and three equations).  It seems like there is a unique solution.

Comment: So basically you are telling me (a) sorry, you still have to row reduce (b) I misread the question. I thought it was asking for an orthogonal basis, not a basis for its orthogonal complement. (c) isn't that still row-reduction?

Comment: Basically this whole problem is row reduction, is what i concluded.

Comment: (a) how do you guess and check?(b) that won't work because it will only be orthogonal to the first vector.

Comment: (a) I wrote something similiar to what you said. But on my paper I missed the -3 (I have no idea how). (b) ah okay, the form is useful, at least for the first two. +1 anyways